# word with diacritic marks not hyphenated

Tags: hyphenation

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa Ut Safgātējomlor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitationies fugit.

Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa Ut Safgatejomlor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitationies fugit.
\end{document}
```

The two paragraphs are equivalent.

The output is

[image]

The word *Safgatejomlor* is hyphenated when the diacritic marks are not used and protruding when diacritic marks are used.

Using `babel` as in

```
\documentclass[latvian, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
...
```

does not provide a solution.

What is the advice to follow?

Comment: use an unicode engine like lualatex. Unrelated but \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} is unneeded, utf8 is the default since more than five years.

Comment: For a single word you can add `\-` where you want to allow breaking, e.g. `Saf\-gā\-tē\-jom\-lor`, or use `\hyphenation{Saf-gā-tē-jom-lor}`. Anyway, English is LaTeX default and you don't set another language.

Comment: It depends on the diacritics. Some are supported in the T1 encoding, others aren't. For instance, `ā` and `ē` aren't, so they're realized with the `\accent` primitive, that disallows hyphenation. In any case, using `babel` for foreign languages is the first thing to attempt.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, how to invoke lualatex?

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: What does "Safgātējomlor" mean? :-)

Comment: @Mico, it is a word created for this example and doesn't have a meaning

Comment: @Viesturs - Maybe it's not surprising that LaTeX has no idea how to hyphenate a made-up word.

Comment: I didn't see a language setting, even when you use babel. Many languages (including European) do not have words with macron diacritical, thus no hyphenation pattern.